# recovery of data from unknown file system HDD

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning, testdisk

I need to recover my files from my external HD. Any help is greatly appreciated.
I have a 2TB external hard, i made a mistake and tried to make it bootable ubuntu installation disk from the .iso file. But now all my files are gone. I was trying to run testdisk on it when he asked me for my partition type table (which i didn't know). Here is the info returned from gdisk of my device.

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.1

Partition table scan:

  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format.
***************************************************************

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by 33 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

Disk /dev/sdc: 3906963456 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 3F2CE61B-F286-49AA-A158-18F0D35517BD
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3906963422
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      3906963455   1.8 TiB     0700  Microsoft basic data
```

Also gparted says it's an unknown file system 1.82 TiB device.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your disk uses the [Master Boot Record (MBR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partitioning system, which is still probably the most common type on hard disks. Note that the partitioning system is entirely distinct from the *filesystem,* which is what's important in accessing the files on the disk. Try typing the following command:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sdb?
```

(Change `/dev/sdb` to whatever the disk identifier is. This will be helpful in identifying the filesystem(s) used on your disk's partition(s). (Note also that the `?` is a wildcard; the intent is to apply `blkid` to every partition on the disk; I'm not asking a question in that command.)

If the filesystem is damaged, you may be able to repair it with the Linux `fsck` command in Linux or OS X or `CHKDSK` in Windows, depending on what the filesystem is. If the filesystem is badly damaged, you may need to resort to [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) or something similar to recover individual files.

The *complete* output of the `gdisk -l` command might have been helpful, although what you've shown indicates that there is at least one partition on the disk. It's conceivable that it had two or more but that one partition has been completely wiped out, though, so showing the complete output, with partition tables, may be worthwhile. Edit your question, and add four spaces to each line of program output to keep the site from reformatting the lines and rendering the entire output illegible. (I've made this edit to your original `gdisk` output.)

---

**Edit:** It looks like you've accidentally overwritten the contents of your external disk with an Ubuntu 14.04 installation image, thus severely damaging the original filesystem. Chances are you won't be able to recover everything from that disk, but PhotoRec (referenced above) may enable you to recover something.

Comment: Thanks Rod, this is the result of my blkid (it's only this one line): "/dev/sdc1: LABEL="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" "

Comment: and the output of gdisk is edited in the question to show it completely.

Comment: See my edit, above.